# MUI: The `value` provided to the Tabs component is invalid. The Tab with this `value` ("0") is not part of the document layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I am using MUI tabs, and I'm having the following error:

MUI: The `value` provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
The Tab with this `value` ("0") is not part of the document layout.
Make sure the tab item is present in the document or that it's not `display: none`.

The code is very similar to the MUI examples which also are generating this same problem

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe not the best one, but it works

I understood the problem is that the Tabs component try to load its children Tab before they exist. So the idea is to introduce a delay in their generation using setTimeout:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index} = props;

    return (
        value === index && (
                <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        )
    );
}

export default function BasicTabs() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
    const [activateTab, setActivateTab] = React.useState(false);

    setTimeout(()=>{
        setActivateTab(true)
    },100)

    const tabsArr=[
        {
            label:"Item One",
            key: `simple-tab-0`,
        },
        {
            label:"Item Two",
            key: `simple-tab-1`,
        }
    ]

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
        <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
                <Tabs value = {value} onChange = {handleChange}>
                    {activateTab && (
                            tabsArr.map((item)=>(
                                <Tab {...item} />
                            ))
                        )
                    }
                </Tabs>
            </Box>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>Item One</TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>Item Two</TabPanel>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

If it don't work, you can try to increase the delay

Comment: so it means that it's actually a bug in MUI, I'm using material-ui v5.9.3

Comment: It didn't solve the problem in my case, and btw instead of using setTimeout() try using `useEffect(()=>{},[])`

Comment: I tried to use useEffect and it didn't work here for me. I'm using mui/materiaI 5.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Use `useState(0)` instead of `useState('0')` that fixed it for me

Answer (score -2):

So, I have been wrestling with this problem for about a month now in a project that was started a few months ago with MUI v5.10.9. I have tried every trick that I could scrape from all the sources over the Internet (not many though), but **nothing worked for me until I upgraded to v5.11.4** just a few minutes ago and the console error is no more there!  Hurray! Probably they have fixed it in recent updates.

So, folks, just upgrade your MUI dependency version.

Comment: I still have the error with v5.11.11...